# grub boot menu not showing after arch installation

Tags: arch-linux, grub

After installing arch linux, grub doesn't show the boot menu. Instead I get a grub prompt.
`/dev/nvme0n1p1` is the efi partition.
`/dev/nvme0n1p2` is the swap partition
`/dev/nvme0n1p3` is the file system partition

First, I mounted the nvme0n1p3 and nvme0n1p1 partitions by using 
`mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt` and `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot` respectively.

After running `arch-chroot /mnt` and installing everything I run

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --recheck --removable.
```

Then I installed the configuration file for grub with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
Then I exited the chroot and `umount -R /mnt`. Then I rebooted. After starting up again, I only get a grub prompt. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you didn't actually install everything. Take a look at [this](https://www.archlinux.org/news/base-group-replaced-by-mandatory-base-package-manual-intervention-required/).

> Be aware that `base` as it stands does not currently contain:
>
> - A kernel
> - An editor
>    ... and other software that you might expect. **You will have to install these separately on new installations.**

Please make sure to **always follow step by step the [Arch Wiki Installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages).**

For your current problem, make sure to also pacstrap `linux` and `linux-firmware`.

Comment: Ok, I only installed base and base-devel

Comment: I first have to try this out